# An error occurred while attempting to login via your social network account

Tags: django, django-allauth

Hi I am using django allauth I am getting this error every things in fine in code and api settings

An error occurred while attempting to login via your social network account.

Comment: facebook is redirecting me on this url

Comment: what kind of error ..?